# What is the methodology for solving algorithms to difficult problems and how does it apply to this example?

Tags: algorithm

I was working on a project for fun but it eventually led me to a difficult unrelated  problem that I can't solve.  So this is a two part question

1. Are there any formal methodologies for solving difficult algorithmic problems (how to rule out different ideas, etc) that can be applied to this problem?
2. Any suggestions on a solution for this problem?

Most algorithms that I run into in daily life usually seem straight forward and just involve problem breakdown/simplification and can almost always be solved with brute force in the worst case scenario.  This problem is different.

> A
>
> 1. Acme company manufactures all different kinds of components
>      (everything from basic circuit boards to complete computers)
> 2. Each component is defined to be made of parts or other components
> 3. Acme receives parts from suppliers at irregular intervals
> 4. Each component has a priority (maybe it is more important to build
>      motherboards than monitors)
> 5. Priorities can change based on constraints (such as if there are
>      less than 3 monitors in stock, wait for parts to build monitors)
>
>    Q: What should Acme build?

I think a possible way to solve this would be to have a tree of all the different components organized such that the highest priority items are at the top.  Traverse each node based on priority and at each node, check if we need to wait for parts for this component or if we can build the next lower priority item.  I could probably even move components up and down the priority tree based on what has been built.  Fiddling around with that idea, I think I could get something to work.  There could be many valid solutions to the problem but I only need to return one valid set.

However, if I want to make the problem a bit more real world, I have additional features

> B.
>
> 1. Each component requires parts + tools + human resources to build.

I think this can be solved similarly to the first case with tools and human resources just being consumable parts.  But now it gets hard

> C
>
> 1. Each part, tool, human resource has some sort of quality
>      associated with it
> 2. Lower quality takes more time to produce
> 3. Time is defined based on some relation between parts, tools, and human
>      resources...so if you have good human resources and good tools, time
>      will be less than if you have bad resources and bad tools
> 4. there may be a limited number of tools/people so they need to be scheduled
>
> The problem can be adjusted to what should we built over the next month or something

How would seasoned algorithm developers go about solving this?

Comment: It sounds like you're describing the field of operations research. An introduction to that doesn't really fit in the StackOverflow format. You might try the Wikipedia entry, or flip through a textbook.

Comment: While I appreciate your feedback, I do feel that this is an algorithm problem.  On the stackoverflow FAQ, it specifically mentions that this site is for software algorithms.  I would like to know how to deal with this problem and similar ones in the future that aren't so straight forward.  I find lately that questions are closed a little too quickly on stackoverflow sometimes and I believe this question has merit.

Comment: Whether a question has merit isn't the only factor, it also needs to be a good fit to the Q&A format. Overly broad questions don't work that well, as there tends not to be any unambiguously correct answers, just discussion.

Comment: Understood.  However, there could be someone out there who knows a solution to this problem.  Perhaps it is some semi-famous John Doe's algorithm.  As for the algorithm methodology, perhaps there are formal methods for addressing algorithms just like there are formal methods for addressing software (agile for example). I don't know the answer to these things which is why I ask on SO. If you know for certain that there are no formal methods and there is no algorithm, then I think it makes sense to put that answer in rather than close the question.

Comment: There are formal methods for dealing with the class of problems you have sketched out: it's the major topic in operations research!

Comment: I have to agree with Michael here.  The problem you describe is _exactly_ the sort of thing that Operations Research was developed to address.  It's a big big field.  Try taking a look at the Wikipedia page for [inventory theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inventory_theory).

Comment: I guess operations research (and Luchian's answer which is probably closer to what I was imagining when I asked) is likely as close as I can get to an answer to part (2) of the question... I guess I am ok if this question is considered bad and fail's to pass SO's moderators.  It happens sometimes. I am still interested in part(1) but I think now that I understand a bit better, I might be able to be a bit more specific for that part too or even avoid having to ask altogether.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like each item has an absolute cost associated with it, which includes costs of other items, resources and priority. Being able to calculate this cost of each item and choosing the item with the lowest or highest cost (depending on how you look at it) would yield the building order for items. However, I'm afraid that a formula to calculate such a "master" cost varies from case to case and only knowing the full specifications would help in building the formula. Even so, you might need to adjust it on the fly to optimize efficiency.

Comment: hmmm...so part of the problem is finding an effective way to determine the cost.  In part (A) of the problem, the cost was simply the priority I guess.

Comment: I'm saying the solution is probably highly dependent on the exact specifications. For example, you could start building a PC if you were missing the processor, probably not if you were missing the motherboard.

Comment: As for the algorithm: always build whatever has the lowest(or highest) cost at one specific time. The "at one specific time" is very important here, as from what I can tell from your description, the cost changes continuously. I guess the real challenge here is finding a fast, reliable solution for calculating the cost.